# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown' while using KNN

Tags: python, knn

I am new to python and trying to run KNN but when I input the code, I get the error ValueError: Unknown label type:'unknown'.
I have encoded all the categorical data and dropped the ones I don't need to avoid dummy trapping.
What else do I need to do to clear this?

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score

training_accuracy = []
test_accuracy = []    
neighbors_settings = range(1, 11)

for n_neighbors in neighbors_settings:
     knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors)
     knn.fit(x_train, y_train)
     train_pred=knn.predict(x_train)
     test_pred=knn.predict(x_test)   

training_accuracy.append(fbeta_score(y_train, train_pred, beta=1))
test_accuracy.append(fbeta_score(y_test, test_pred, beta=1))

plt.plot(neighbors_settings, training_accuracy, label="training accuracy")
plt.plot(neighbors_settings, test_accuracy, label="test accuracy")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.xlabel("n_neighbors")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('knn_compare_model')
```

I expect a graph to show the test and training accuracy but I get this below;

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-8a3a1f3c5c24> in <module>

    11     # build the model    
    12     knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors)     
---> 13     knn.fit(x_train, y_train)
>
    14     
    15     # if accuracy of prediction on training set is high but it is low 
           on test set: So overfitting     

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in fit(self, X, y)
    903             self.outputs_2d_ = True    
    904     
    --> 905         check_classification_targets(y)
    906         self.classes_ = []   
    907         self._y = np.empty(y.shape, dtype=np.int)    
>
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in 
   check_classification_targets(y)
    169     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass- multioutput', 
    >
    170                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:    
    --> 171         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    >
    172    
    173    

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

Comment: could you just share the entire trace back error, along with the types of `x_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: @ParthasarathySubburaj I have added the trace back error code

Comment: can you print the type of y and see what it is? I think that your labels are of type `object` which sklearn can't recognize.

Comment: @ParthasarathySubburaj I don't understand what you mean when you say print the type of y? I used the concatenate function to merge to dataframes together and removed duplicated before running this train and test code, could that have affected it andhow can i resolve it?

Comment: Can you just print the they type and shape of `X_train` and `y_train` before they are fed into the `fit` method?

Comment: I will be really happy if you could accept this as a verified answer so that others might also benefit from this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Your `y_train` could be of object type which could cause this error, so kindly add the line

`y_train = y_train.astype('int')`

before

`knn.fit(x_train, y_train)`

Also do the same with your `y_test`.